# how to passing js variable to a native modal by clicking <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

i have a problem to passing js variable to a native (non-bootstrap) modal. here's my code:

```
<a class="big-blue-button" id="seminor-enroll">
                        <h:outputLabel value="入会申し込み"/>
                    </a>

                    <a class="big-orange-button" id="seminor-trial">
                        <h:outputLabel value="体験申し込み"/>
                    </a>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $("a.big-blue-button").click(function(){
                            var id = $("a.big-blue-button").attr("id");
                            showModal(id);
                            document.getElementById('applyType').value = id;
                        });
                    </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $("a.big-orange-button").click(function(){
                            var id = $("a.big-orange-button").attr("id");
                            showModal(id);
                            document.getElementById('applyType').value = id;
                        });
                    </script>
```

when i click `<a class="big-blue-button" id="seminor-enroll">` i want that `<a id="seminor-enroll"/>` is save as value of `<h:inputHidden>` tag in modal form.

this is my modal code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content ui-g-12 ui-lg-6 ui-md-8 ui-sm-10">

            <div class="ui-g" style="position: relative">
                <span class="close">&#x2573;</span>
                <div class="ui-g-12">
                    <div class="ui-g-12">

                        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-sm-12 user-form-panel ui-fluid">
                            <h:form>

                                <div class="ui-g-12" style="text-align:initial">
                                    //in this inputHidden i want get that <a> id value
                                    <h:inputHidden id="applyType" value="#{memberBean.applyType}" />
                                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-person" value="ログイン" ajax="false" action="#{memberBean.login()}" style="float:left"/>
                                    <p:link styleClass="ui-button" outcome="/index.html" value="ホームに戻る" style="margin-left: 5%; float:left;border-radius:3px;line-height: 30px;"/>
                                </div>
                            </h:form>
                            <p class="or-text" style="text-align:center;">OR</p>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

and final result i want that value (from `<a id>` to `<h:inputHidden`) show in jsf bean just like this:

```
public String login() {

    System.out.println(applyType);

    return "";
}
```

is this possible to do that?

Comment: You could replace the <a/> by a <h:commandLink/>, then add an <f:ajax/> tag inside the link. Then add a listener to the link. Add a listener method in your bean. Now you should be able to click the link and in you bean it should be possible to retrieve the id from the event. Set the id to a String field in your bean. Should work then.

Comment: almost done, when we using <h:commandLink> system will rendered <a> tag with href="#" atribute which means after modal open then that page will reload and cancel the modal, the question is, how to remove href="#" on commandLink render?

Comment: Hmm i don't know if it is possible by returning an empty string from the action-method. If that is not possible and there is no other way (i don't really get your point :S) you could write your own renderer or your own link using a custom component :)